# Full screen div width with limited body width

Tags: html, css

Working with a shopify template where body has a max-width of 1200 pixels.
I need one div to have a full screen width. As you can understand, I can't remove that max width, since it's going to mess up entire template. Is there any way around it except fixed pixel width?
Thanks!

edit:
Not adding html since it's just one div.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px)
body {
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#topcontainer {
width:100%;
right:0;
left:0;
height:50px;
background-color:#D8D8D8 !important;
border-bottom: 2px solid #BCBCBD;
z-index:22;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a div with `position: absolute; top:0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%` or else you can apply your CSS to `<html>`

Answer (score 0):

Would `position: absolute; right: 0; left: 0;` on the element you want to stretch do the trick? It is hard to tell without seeing the markup and corresponding styles. Maybe put together a quick jsfiddle.

Comment: It's in media query, so, not sure if fiddle will help. Added css to initial post though. Tried your advice and Tushar's. Didn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Add following class to div

```
.fullScreen { width:100%; margin:auto; }
```

Comment: That will not work since it'd be a child of BODY which has a max-width set.

Comment: This will work as body always take 100% of your browser width.

Comment: No this will not unless it is positioned absolutely.